# TypeError at /pyworld/post/New Post Slug 2/

Tags: django

Помогите пожалуйста с ошибкой TypeError at /pyworld/post/New Post Slug 2/
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import *

def py(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog\index.html', context={'posts':post})

def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail_url.html', context={{'post':post}})
# Create your views here.
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', py, name = 'post_list_url'),
    path('post/<str:slug>/', post_detail, name='post_detail_url')
]
```

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index = True )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)


# Create your models here.
```

Traceback

```
    Internal Server Error: /pyworld/post/New Post Slug 2/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\valer\Desktop\PyWorld\PyWorld\blog\views.py", line 11, in post_detail
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail_url.html', context={{'post':post}})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
[04/Nov/2018 20:17:06] "GET /pyworld/post/New%20Post%20Slug%202/ HTTP/1.1" 500 64706
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в файле views.py на 11 строке
поменяй
     `return render(request, 'blog/post_detail_url.html', context={{'post':post}})`

на

```
return render(request, 'blog/post_detail_url.html', context={'post':post})
```